# redirection using patterns through .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone help me on htaccess pattern redirection ? The problem is as follows:

I have dynamic urls like `http://somesite.com/house/name-name-name-12345` or 
`http://somesite.com/house/name-12345` . I mean the URL pattern in house name - houseid. and the house name is concatenated with "-". Like if the name is "some house name"  then the name is like 
`some-house-name`.

Now I have to 301 redirect through `.htaccess` file like

`http://somesite.com/house/name-name-name-12345` => `http://somesite.com/house/12345`

or

`http://somesite.com/house/name-name-12345` => `http://somesite.com/house/12345`

or

`http://somesite.com/house/name-12345` => `http://somesite.com/house/12345`

for every dynamic urls. So how can I get that ?

Tried (from comment) :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /house/(.*)-(.*)
RewriteRule ^ /house/%2
```

Comment: Have you tried something ? What do you want exactly ? URL redirection (301) or internal rewriting ?

Comment: URL redirection (301). I want a url redirection code in htaccess so that i can move http://somesite.com/house/name-name-name-12345 to
http://somesite.com/house/12345
or
http://somesite.com/house/name-12345 to 

http://somesite.com/house/12345

I have tried with the following
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /house/(.*)-(.*)#
RewriteRule ^ /house/%2 but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^house/(.+)-([0-9]+)$ http://somesite.com/house/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks okio ... But I have still some issues like when i am giving like housename-1-123456 or -t-dsdf---bungalow-123456 or in-de-tyhu-name-2-pers--12345 .. and when I am testing this after 5-6 tests times I found "Unable to connect" with server.. Can u explain

Comment: No idea for the "Unable to connect". I have just edited my answer for the different case you point out.